# Ampersands in URL problems

Tags: .htaccess, url, ampersand

I have a php page which creates URL like:

```
vendors/London City/cat-DJ & Entertainment/keywords
```

which my .htaccess redirects as shown below

```
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)/(.+)$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2&freetext=$3 [L]
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)/(.+)/$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2&freetext=$3 [L]
```

**problem 1 is :** in the vendors.php file, I am getting only "DJ ; Entertainment" as category. The ampersand is missing.

**Problem 2** is : My complete .htaccess file is shown below... **6 rules** are defined.

```
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/(.+)/$ vendors.php?location=$1&freetext=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/(.+)$  vendors.php?location=$1&freetext=$2 [L]
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)/$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)$  vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)/(.+)$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2&freetext=$3[L]
RewriteRule vendors/(.+)/cat-(.+)/(.+)/$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2&freetext=$3[L]
```

Why the URL **vendors/London City/cat-DJ & Entertainment/keywords** is matching with rule 3 or 4 and redirecting to vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2 ?

Does .htaccess Process the rules from top to beginning one by one?

I had solved the problem by putting the rules 5 and 6 at the top of other rules. Did I make the correct fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** I don't really like the idea of having spaces and other special characters in the URLs. I don't know if it's possible with your site, but instead of this kind of URL

```
vendors/London City/cat-DJ & Entertainment/keywords
```

you should have this one:

```
vendors/london-city/cat-dj-and-entertainment/keywords
```

For that, of course, you will have to perform some additional transformations / lookups in your database to convert `london-city` back to `London City` and `dj-and-entertainment` back to `DJ & Entertainment`. This can be done by storing these "from-to" pairs in database.

**2.** In any case -- **order of rules matters**. Therefore you should start with more specific rules and end up with more generic rules.

Also -- the `(.+)` pattern is a way too broad as it can match `hello` as well as `hello/pink/kitten`. To ensure that you always grab only one section (part of URL between `/`) use `([^/]+)` pattern instead -- this will address one of the aspects of your "prob #2".

Therefore, try these optimized rules (each rule will match the URL with and without trailing slash):

```
RewriteRule ^vendors/([^/]+)/cat-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2&freetext=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^vendors/([^/]+)/cat-([^/]+)/?$ vendors.php?location=$1&category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^vendors/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ vendors.php?location=$1&freetext=$2 [L]
```

> Also I'm not getting the value of 'category' with the Ampersand as
>   given in the url. I am getting only semi-colon. What can be the
>   reason?

I do not have Apache box currently running next to me, so cannot check it right now, but try adding `B` or `NE` flag next to the `L` flag (e.g. `[L,B]`) -- one of them should help:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> The order in which these rules are defined is important - this is the order in which they will be applied at run-time.

Comment: ok, but regarding prob2, I have included $ at the end of every rule, it should not match with rules 3,4 initially.

Also I'm not getting the value of 'category' with the Ampersand as given in the url. I am getting only semi-colon. What can be the reason?